# PHP DOMDocument value of element without child-elements

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I got a DOMDocument which looks like this:

```
<font size="6" face="Arial">
CONTENT
    <font size="5" face="Arial">...</font>
    <br>
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="3" bgcolor="#E7E7E7" rules="all">...</table>
    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">...</table>
    <font size="3" face="Arial" color="#000000">...</font>
</font>
```

Now I want to get just CONTENT and not all the other child-elements.

How can I do that?

Comment: IIRC, in valid HTML, you can't nest a `<table>` within `<font>`.

Comment: how do you get Domdocument??? are trying get result on server side or client side...

Comment: Might be, the code is generated by a 3rd party program and I gotta parse it.

Comment: font??????????????????? get over it !!!
<font color="red">It's deprecated </font>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter:

```
$output = $xml->getElementsByTagName("font")->item(1)firstChild->textContent;
```

nickb's solution works too and is even better if the CONTENT comes after one of the sub-childs. But since it doesn't do that in my case, this one is shorter.

Comment: Works nicely if I remove the 'item(1)' part!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is grab the first [`DOMText`](http://php.net/domtext) node that's a child of the first `<font>` tag.

```
// Get the first <font> tag
$font = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'font')->item(0);

// Find the first DOMText element
$first_text = null;
foreach( $font->childNodes as $child) {
    if( $child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        $first_text = $child; 
        break;
    }
}

if( $first_text != null) {
    echo 'OUTPUT: ' . $first_text->textContent;
}
```

You can see from [the demo](http://viper-7.com/15CfYr) that this prints:

```
OUTPUT: CONTENT
```